# How to display all array values once and in random order?

Tags: php, arrays, random

I need a PHP script for my website in order to pick (all) values from an array and display them randomly.

Every value must be shown only once.

This is the code I've written so far, the problem is that the values are not taken once.

```
<?php
$one = 'SITE 1<br><br>';
$two = 'SITE 2<br><br>';
$three = 'SITE 3<br><br>';
$four = 'SITE 4<br><br>';
$five = 'SITE 5<br><br>';

$array = array($one, $two, $three, $four, $five);
for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    echo $array[rand(0, count($array) - 1)] . "\n";
}
?>
```

You can test this code directly here: https://www.fabriziorocca.it/test/phprandom.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use shuffle:

```
<?php
$one = 'SITE 1<br><br>';
$two = 'SITE 2<br><br>';
$three = 'SITE 3<br><br>';
$four = 'SITE 4<br><br>';
$five = 'SITE 5<br><br>';

$array = array($one, $two, $three, $four, $five);
shuffle($array);
foreach($array as $item) {
    echo $item . "\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH) in /public_html/test/phprandom.php on line 10

Comment: I'm sorry, i forgot the `;` after shuffle. Try again